# Creating an ordered list using UILabels in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uicollectionview

In Xcode 5, I understand that by using the following method you're able to change the label's text:

```
cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{section: %ld, item: %ld}" , 
    (long)indexPath.row, (long)indexPath.section];
```

This is fine, if you wanted the cell ids CollectionView to have the same word and with numbers in ascending  order.

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

How do I create an ordered list for the UIlabel so that I can create a custom label for the different images?

Some help here as clearly as possible would be greatly received... :)

Comment: what is text.cell.label.text ??

Comment: error on my part, fixed.

Comment: Hey can you be a bit more clear please? What I understand now is you have a collection view in which you are setting the label's text as the current indepath's row and section. What you want to do now?

Comment: apply individual names for the array of images that appear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood what you want but the major steps when creating TableViews/CollectionViews are the following:

1. Define the layout of your custom cell according to your needs.
2. Create an array to hold the data to populate each cell.
3. Implement the delegate/datasource methods from the component you are using (UICollectionView, for instance). There's one delegate method where you create the cells for a given item (collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: if you are working with UICollectionView). There you will load your cell and set its content using the data from the array you created.

There's a good tutorial about UICollectionView here http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

If you are not familiar with UITableView I would suggest you to start working with tables before you dive into collectionViews.
Check this blog for a list of tutorials about UITableViews http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-uitableview-tutorial-for-beginners-part-1/

Comment: Just to be clear, I've created a colletionview with an array of images. So what I need to do now is apply individual names to the images through one cell ID so the viewer knows what the picture is called.